# How to run a docker login command as a different user?

Tags: linux, docker

How to run a docker login command as a different user?

```
sudo -u gitlab-runner docker login xxx
```

error:

```
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at <unix:///var/run/docker.sock>: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.30/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

i even tried this:

```
su - gitlab-runner -c docker login xxx
```

Comment: Have you tried the `--username, -u` flags for `docker login` as per the docs here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#usage

Comment: i want to run a docker login command as a different user, say for example docker login command should be run as user called "sam"
docker login -u flag is for setting the username for the registry

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](https://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the user to the docker group

```
 sudo usermod -a -G docker gitlab-runner
```

and then execute this command:

```
sudo -u gitlab-runner docker login xxx
```